# Passing parameters to a form, via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a form which passes a number of parameters. So far, the stock parameters are being passed:

```
var params = "title=" + document.getElementById("title").value + 
             "&url=" + document.getElementById("url").value + 
             "&snippet=" + document.getElementById("snippet").value +
             "&tags=" + document.getElementById("tags").value +
             "&status_bookmark=" + document.getElementById("status_bookmark").value +
             "&comment=" + document.getElementById("comment").value +
             "&status_comment=" + document.getElementById("status_comment").value;
```

I'm attempting to append additional form elements to this parameter string, which are:

```
var i, lng = document.getElementById('addbookmark').length;
// If the length property is undefined, then there is only one checkbox.
if (typeof lng === "undefined") {
    params + "&topic-link-item-1=" + document.getElementById("topic-link-item-1").value;
    params + "&topic-link-comment-box-1=" + document.getElementById("topic-link-comment-box-1").value;
}
else {
    for (i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        params + "&topic-link-item-" + i + "=" + document.getElementById("topic-link-item-" + i).value;
        params + "&topic-link-comment-box-" + i + "=" + document.getElementById("topic-link-comment-box-" + i).value;
    }
}
```

Here, I've used code taken from [another StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838667/javascript-count-checked-checkbox), and as you can see, I'm trying to build up a series of paired parameters that match the ad hoc form elements I'm generating elsewhere via jQuery, which works.

However, these values appear not be getting passed via the form, while the other form elements are being passed.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

I've revised the code, per the suggestions, but it's not working:

```
var i, formObj = document.form['addbookmark'], formObjLng = document.form['addbookmark'].length;
// If the length property is undefined, then there is only one checkbox.
if ((typeof formObjLng !== "undefined")) {
    for (i = 0; i < formObjLng; i++) {
        if ((formObj.elements['topic-link-item-' + i].type == "checkbox") && (formObj.elements['topic-link-item-' + i].checked)) {
            params = params + "&topic-link-item-" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-item-" + i)).value;
            params = params + "&topic-link-comment-box-" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-comment-box-" + i)).value;
        }
    }
}
```

As for the form, it's simply a form with an ID of "addbookmark", and to again state what I said earlier, everything else works with the exception of what Im attempting here.

Comment: Where is the "form" you mention?  Is there an actual html form element?

Comment: Is your form [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) or [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)? If your server-side code is expecting POST, then passing parameters via GET is not going to work.

Comment: What is addbookmark ? If it is a form element, use form['name'].elements['elementname'].type to detect the type of form  element (checkbox, etc.).

Comment: Show us your server-side code which processes these paramters.

Comment: Hi guys, as I said, everything else except the above works perfectly; it's just the JavaScript that isn't working.

Comment: @Wayne, that seems like a ridiculous statement to me.  "Everything else works except what I'm attempting here."  Everyone here seems to be offering suggestions and good questions to help discover the context around your problem, which you don't seem eager to offer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code. You need to URL encode the values using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function. Also you need to assign the result back to the `params` variable when concatenating:

```
var params = 
    "title=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("title").value) + 
    "&url=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("url").value) + 
    "&snippet=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("snippet").value) +
    "&tags=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("tags").value) +
    "&status_bookmark=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("status_bookmark").value) +
    "&comment=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("comment").value) +
    "&status_comment=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("status_comment").value);
```

and also for the other values that you are adding:

```
var i, lng = document.getElementById('addbookmark').length;
// If the length property is undefined, then there is only one checkbox.
if (typeof lng === "undefined") {
    params += "&topic-link-item-1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-item-1").value);
    params += "&topic-link-comment-box-1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-comment-box-1").value);
}
else {
    for (i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        params += "&topic-link-item-" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-item-" + i).value);
        params += "&topic-link-comment-box-" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-comment-box-" + i).value);
    }
}
```

Notice how:

```
params += "&topic-link-item-" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-item-" + i).value);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
params = params + "&topic-link-item-" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-item-" + i).value);
```

is not the same as what you were doing initially:

```
params + "&topic-link-item-" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("topic-link-item-" + i).value);
```

You were simply concatenating 2 values and never assigning the result back to the `params` variable.

Comment: Hi Darin, as I said, the first series of parameters are working. It's just the second series that aren't.

Comment: No, they are working because the user didn't enter a dangerous character in those textboxes. As soon as he enters for example the `&` or `=` sign in one of those textboxes everything will break. That's why you need to use the `encodeURIComponent` function. As far as the second problem is concerned, you should assign the result back to the `params` variable as shown in my answer. You should use `params = params + ...` instead of simply `params + ...`. That's why your code is not working.

Comment: I've made changes to reflect your recommendation.

Comment: No, the additions you suggested break everything. Also, they're not required, as I perform form validation within the application itself. Even with the encodeURIComponent() removed, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Javascript doesnt' allow text append the way you are doing it.

Should be

params = params +

Comment: I've made changes to reflect your recommendation.