# Count the number of checked checkboxes in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, onchange

So basically i want to count the number of checkboxes that are ticked. I get my code to the point where it counts them successfully, but I want to put in an alert that shows the number of checkboxes ticked, the code does this but doesn't show the total count, it increments the total every refresh. I just want to know how I can show a total count.

It should display the total when the radio button 'yes' is clicked.

```html
<br />Apples
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />Oranges
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />Mango
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />
<br />Yes
<input type="radio" name="yesorno" id="yes" onchange="checkboxes()"
```

```js
function checkboxes(){
    var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked === true){
        count++;
        alert(count);
    }
}}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript count checked checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838667/javascript-count-checked-checkbox)

Comment: different question @JohnConde

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length`

Answer (score 55):

This should do the trick:

`alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);`

Comment: alert(document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length-1);

Comment: There is no point in subtracting one. Length returns the number of checkboxes that are ticked (which is the length of the array)

Comment: i put your line of code in JSFiddle and it was giving me numbed of ticked boxes + 1 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvH7R/2/)

Comment: It was counting checked checkboxes and radio buttons. Since you want to count only checkboxes, use `alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);`

Comment: Sooo clever! Thank you

Answer (score 23):

try this using jquery

Method 1:

```
alert($('.checkbox_class_here :checked').size());
```

Method 2:

```
alert($('input[name=checkbox_name]').attr('checked'));
```

Method: 3

```
alert($(":checkbox:checked").length);
```

Comment: yeah need to javascript

Comment: While this *is* Javascript, technically, the user did not mention JQuery. You shouldn't assume people are using a library they've not mentioned.

Comment: This is still a useful answer for those who happened on this question and are using jQuery. It doesn't matter if the OP didn't mention it, the answer says 'try using...'

Comment: PS, for Method 1, no space needed between :checked and class name.

Comment: In the first method use length instead of size() [Deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/size/)

Comment: As Antony D says, `alert($('.classNameHere:checked').length);`, no space.  Cheers, jz

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Marlon Bernardes for this. 
`alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);`

If you have more than one form with different checkbox names in each, the above code will count all checkboxes in all forms.

To get over this, you can modify it to isolate by name.

```
var le = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="chkboxes[]"]:checked').length;
```

Comment: SyntaxError: 'input[name="foo"]:checked' is not a valid selector (Firefox 57)

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

```
 <br />Apples
                <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" checked/>Oranges
                <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />Mango
                <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />

                <br />Yes
<input type="radio" name="yesorno" id="yes" onClick="checkboxes();" />
```

Javascript

```
     function checkboxes()
      {
       var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        count = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
           if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true){
              count++;
              alert(count);
           }

        }
     }
```

[<kbd>**FIDDLE DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/RvH7R/)

Comment: thats what i have no except the 'onClick' change. I am trying to prevent the 3 alert messages that pop up if 3 check boxes are ticked.

Comment: @roro `alert(count);` put outside from loop.

Answer (score 3):

The initial code was very nearly right. the line
alert(count);
was in the wrong place. It should have come after the second closing brace like this:-

```
 function checkboxes()
  {
   var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
       if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true){
          count++;
       }
    }
    alert(count);
 }
```

In the wrong place it was giving you an alert message with every checked box.

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("fruit");
for(i = 0 ; i<checkboxes.length; i++)
{
if(checkboxes[i].checked==0){checkboxes.splice(i,1);}
}
alert("Number of checked checkboxes: "+checkboxes.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkboxes(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var inputObj;
  var selectedCount = 0;
    for(var count1 = 0;count1<inputs.length;count1++) {
        inputObj = inputs[count1];
        var type = inputObj.getAttribute("type");
        if (type == 'checkbox' && inputObj.checked) {
            selectedCount++;
        }
    }
  alert(selectedCount);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>Fruits
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" checked/>Oranges
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />Mango
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />Apple
  <br />Yes
  <input type="radio" name="yesorno" id="yes"       onClick="checkboxes();"/>
  </body>
</html>
```