# Count total number of checkboxes what are checked and show on page via JS

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to show the total number of checkboxes that user has selected on the page. Here is my code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />C

<p>Total Number of Items Selected = <p>
```

Please provide the javascript code needed to achieve this. I know this has been asked before but i failed to benefit from those answers as they required me to edit the JS code to fit to my HTML, which i am not capable of at this point.

Comment: My bad, flagged with the wrong link. Should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938341/count-the-number-of-checked-checkboxes-in-html/22938796

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate the number of html checkbox checked using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957290/calculate-the-number-of-html-checkbox-checked-using-jquery)

Comment: I know some people have asked this type of questions before but i cannot implement that answers given to their questions to my situation as it require manipulating the HTML or JS code. And i am a newbie can cannot do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a querySelector.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length;
```

Note that this will select all checkboxes in the document. If you just want to refer to a certain group of checkboxes, give all the checkboxes in the group the same name and refer to them like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='name']:checked").length;//replace 'name' with the name of the checkboxes
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />C

<p id="result">Total Number of Items Selected = <p>  
<script>
showChecked();
function showChecked(){
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Total Number of Items Selected = " + document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length;
}
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=fruit]").forEach(i=>{
 i.onclick = function(){
  showChecked();
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your suggested solution will select all the `checkbox`'s inside the current document.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki You're right, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Now you've a copy of my suggested solution :D

Comment: @Sali No problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could use **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** method to select all the elements you want to target then use `length` method that will return the number of cheched element like :

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="fruit"]:checked').length;
_______________________________________________^^^^^^^ //Used to select just checked inputs
```

**NOTE:** The use of name selector `input[name="fruit"]` target just the desired input's instead of all the document `checkbox`'s.

**Live example using jQuery :**

```js
$('input[name="fruit"]').click(function() {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="fruit"]:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />C
```

Comment: The question did not mention jQuery.

Comment: `$('input[name="fruit"]')` and `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: That isn't a part of the suggested solution, was there just to show a live example... and you know that

Answer (score 1):

While you've requested a JavaScript solution, this can be achieved with CSS alone:

```css
/* specifies the named counter that will be incremented by
   each checked check-box: */
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  counter-increment: checked;
}

/* shows the counter in the '::after' pseudo-element of the
   sibling <p> element: */
p::after {
  content: ' ' counter(checked);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" />C

<p>Total Number of Items Selected =</p>
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! This is working too ! I did not know it can be achieved via CSS, is this compatible with all browsers old and new ?

Comment: You’d have to check compatibility to be sure – with [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) for example – but I think it’s supported in most browsers, from IE 10 onwards.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your input and for expanding my knowledge i have saved this for future use.