# How do I display number of selected items in checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, checkbox, tags

How do I display the number of selected items?

I've tried different ways to count the checkbox but it did not count the items when I click "select all".

[image]

I want to show the number of these items.

[image]

This is the code I am using.

This is the source of the code.
https://www.freakyjolly.com/jquery-checkbox-list-select-unselect-all-with-indeterminate-master-check-example-tutorial/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="selectAll"
            id="masterCheck"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="masterCheck">
            Select / Unselect All
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="list-wrapper">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item1"
            id="item1"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item1">
            Item 1
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item2"
            id="item2"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item2">
            Item 2
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item3"
            id="item3"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item3">
            Item 3
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item4"
            id="item4"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item4">
            Item 4
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item5"
            id="item5"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item5">
            Item 5
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" id="selected-values"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    // ID selector on Master Checkbox
    var masterCheck = $("#masterCheck");
    // ID selector on Items Container
    var listCheckItems = $("#list-wrapper :checkbox");

    // Click Event on Master Check
    masterCheck.on("click", function() {
      var isMasterChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
      listCheckItems.prop("checked", isMasterChecked);
      getSelectedItems();
    });

    // Change Event on each item checkbox
    listCheckItems.on("change", function() {
      // Total Checkboxes in list
      var totalItems = listCheckItems.length;
      // Total Checked Checkboxes in list
      var checkedItems = listCheckItems.filter(":checked").length;

      //If all are checked
      if (totalItems == checkedItems) {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
        masterCheck.prop("checked", true);
      }
      // Not all but only some are checked
      else if (checkedItems > 0 && checkedItems < totalItems) {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", true);
      }
      //If none is checked
      else {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
        masterCheck.prop("checked", false);
      }
      getSelectedItems();
    });

    function getSelectedItems() {
      var getCheckedValues = [];
      getCheckedValues = [];
      listCheckItems.filter(":checked").each(function() {
        getCheckedValues.push($(this).val());
      });
      $("#selected-values").html(JSON.stringify(getCheckedValues));
    }
  });
```

Comment: javascript `array.length` Simples

Comment: Or replace `getCheckedValues.push($(this).val());` with `cnt++;`  Initialise the counter outside the loop of course

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of checked checkboxes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938341/count-the-number-of-checked-checkboxes-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple `getCheckedValues.length` like:

```js
$(function() {
    // ID selector on Master Checkbox
    var masterCheck = $("#masterCheck");
    // ID selector on Items Container
    var listCheckItems = $("#list-wrapper :checkbox");

    // Click Event on Master Check
    masterCheck.on("click", function() {
      var isMasterChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
      listCheckItems.prop("checked", isMasterChecked);
      getSelectedItems();
    });

    // Change Event on each item checkbox
    listCheckItems.on("change", function() {
      // Total Checkboxes in list
      var totalItems = listCheckItems.length;
      // Total Checked Checkboxes in list
      var checkedItems = listCheckItems.filter(":checked").length;

      //If all are checked
      if (totalItems == checkedItems) {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
        masterCheck.prop("checked", true);
      }
      // Not all but only some are checked
      else if (checkedItems > 0 && checkedItems < totalItems) {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", true);
      }
      //If none is checked
      else {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
        masterCheck.prop("checked", false);
      }
      getSelectedItems();
    });

    function getSelectedItems() {
      var getCheckedValues = [];
      getCheckedValues = [];
      listCheckItems.filter(":checked").each(function() {
        getCheckedValues.push($(this).val());
      });
      $("#selected-values").html(JSON.stringify(getCheckedValues));
      $("#selected-number").html('<p>Number of element selected: '+ getCheckedValues.length + '</p>');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="selectAll"
            id="masterCheck"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="masterCheck">
            Select / Unselect All
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="list-wrapper">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item1"
            id="item1"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item1">
            Item 1
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item2"
            id="item2"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item2">
            Item 2
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item3"
            id="item3"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item3">
            Item 3
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item4"
            id="item4"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item4">
            Item 4
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item5"
            id="item5"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item5">
            Item 5
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" id="selected-values">[]</li>
        <li class="list-group-item" id="selected-number">Number of element selected: 0</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [Array.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)