# How to count checked checkbox using onclick event ref by id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, onclick

How to count checked checkbox using onclick event ref by id?

http://jsfiddle.net/9na5Q/11/

Html is

```
<div id="yyy">
<input type="checkbox" id="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" id="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" id="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<div>
```

and javascript is

```
function xxx()
{
    var zzz = document.getElementById("check_id").length;
    alert(zzz);    
}
```

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page. they are unique by definition. Use class instead

Comment: Answer from Existing Post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872296/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-checked-checkboxes-on-a-page

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838667/javascript-count-checked-checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ids need to be unique. They are unique for the entire document. So the solution is to change this to a classname for example. This is just one of many solutions.

```
<div id="yyy">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="check_id1" onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="check_id2" onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="check_id3" onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="check_id4" onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="check_id5" onclick="checkTotalCheckedBoxes()">
<div>
```

```js
function checkTotalCheckedBoxes()
{
     var checkLength = 0;
     var boxes = document.getElementById("yyy").getElementsByTagName("input");
     for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
     {
         boxes[i].checked ? checkLength++ : null;
     }
     alert (checkLength + " boxes are checked." );
}
```

Comment: @robertwersaq this code is IE7 proof. Iterates over all inputs and adds to the counter when it's checked. Alas no fancy modern functions that made our lifes so easy.

Answer (score 2):

ID's are unique in html. Use classes instead.

Checking for checked checkboxes are much easier to do with jquery, so use it if you are able to.

```js
function xxx()
{
  var zzz = $(".check_id:checked").length;
  alert(zzz);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yyy">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_id" onclick="xxx()">
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){

        var total=0;
        var list =$('input[type="checkbox"]').length;

         var dogsSelected = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
         var numSelected = dogsSelected.length;
         for( var i=0; i <=numSelected; i++) {

            if(numSelected > 10)
            {

          $(".total").addClass('hide');
          $(".oMute").removeClass('hide');


             return false; 
            }
         else {

         $(".oMute").addClass('hide');
          $(".total").removeClass('hide');

         }               
     }

      });  
    });    
   </script>
```

====================================================
Html

```
  <section class="oOpt jsCategory1">
  <h1 class="oH4">Web, Mobile &amp; Software Dev</h1>

  <label for="ci531770282589057025" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Desktop Software Development" class="jsCategory1" name="chk[]" >
  Desktop Software Development</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057026" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Ecommerce Development"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">Ecommerce Development</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057027" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Game Development"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">Game Development</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057024" class="block oOptLbl"
  >
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Mobile Development"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">Mobile Development</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057030" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Product Management"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">Product Management</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057031" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="QA &amp; Testing"   name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">QA &amp; Testing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057028" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Scripts &amp; Utilities"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">Scripts &amp; Utilities</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862733" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Web Development" class="jsCategory1">Web Development</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057029" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Web &amp; Mobile Design"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">Web &amp; Mobile Design</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057032" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Software Development"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory1">Other - Software Development</label>
  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory2">

  <h1 class="oH4">IT &amp; Networking</h1>

  <label for="ci531770282589057033" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Database Administration"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory2">Database Administration</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057034" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="ERP / CRM Software"   name="chk[]" class="jsCategory2">ERP / CRM Software</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057036" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Information Security"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory2">Information Security</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057035" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Network &amp; System Administration"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory2">Network &amp; System Administration</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057037" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - IT &amp; Networking"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory2">Other - IT &amp; Networking</label>
  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory3">
  <h1 class="oH4">Data Science &amp; Analytics</h1>

  <label for="ci531770282593251330" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="A/B Testing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory3">A/B Testing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057039" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Data Visualization"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory3">Data Visualization</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251331" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Data Extraction / ETL"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory3">Data Extraction / ETL</label>

  <label for="ci531770282589057038" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Data Mining &amp; Management"  name="chk[]"  class="jsCategory3">Data Mining &amp; Management</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251329" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Machine Learning"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory3">Machine Learning</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251328" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Quantitative Analysis"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory3">Quantitative Analysis</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251332" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Data Science &amp; Analytics"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory3">Other - Data Science &amp; Analytics</label>

  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory4">

  <h1 class="oH4">Engineering &amp; Architecture</h1>

  <label for="ci531770282601639948" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="3D Modeling &amp; CAD"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">3D Modeling &amp; CAD</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639949" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Architecture"   name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Architecture</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834240" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Chemical Engineering"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Chemical Engineering</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639950" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Civil &amp; Structural Engineering"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Civil &amp; Structural Engineering</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834241" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Contract Manufacturing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Contract Manufacturing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639951" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Electrical Engineering"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Electrical Engineering</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834242" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Interior Design"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Interior Design</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639952" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Mechanical Engineering"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Mechanical Engineering</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639953" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Product Design"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Product Design</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834243" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Engineering &amp; Architecture"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory4">Other - Engineering &amp; Architecture</label>
  </section>

  </div>
  <div class="col col1of3">
  <section class="oOpt jsCategory5">
  <h1 class="oH4">Design &amp; Creative</h1>
  <label for="ci531770282593251333" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Animation"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Animation</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251341" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Audio Production"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Audio Production</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251334" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Graphic Design"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Graphic Design</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251335" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Illustration"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Illustration</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251336" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Logo Design &amp; Branding"  name="chk[]"  class="jsCategory5">Logo Design &amp; Branding</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251340" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Photography"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Photography</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251337" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Presentations"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Presentations</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251338" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Video Production"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Video Production</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251339" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Voice Talent"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Voice Talent</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251342" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Design &amp; Creative"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory5">Other - Design &amp; Creative</label>

  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory6"><h1 class="oH4">Writing</h1>
  <label for="ci531770282597445648" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Academic Writing &amp; Research"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Academic Writing &amp; Research</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445642" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Article &amp; Blog Writing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Article &amp; Blog Writing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445643" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Copywriting"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Copywriting</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445645" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Creative Writing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Creative Writing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445644" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Editing &amp; Proofreading"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Editing &amp; Proofreading</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639936" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Grant Writing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Grant Writing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639937" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Resumes &amp; Cover Letters"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Resumes &amp; Cover Letters</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445646" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Technical Writing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Technical Writing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445647" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Web Content"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Web Content</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639938" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Writing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory6">Other - Writing</label>

  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory7">
  <h1 class="oH4">Translation</h1>
  <label for="ci531770282601639939" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="General Translation"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory7">General Translation</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639940" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Legal Translation"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory7">Legal Translation</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639942" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Medical Translation"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory7">Medical Translation</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639941" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Technical Translation"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory7">Technical Translation</label>

  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory8">
  <h1 class="oH4">Legal</h1>
  <label for="ci531770282605834246" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Contract Law"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory8">Contract Law</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834245" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Corporate Law"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory8">Corporate Law</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834247" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Criminal Law"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory8">Criminal Law</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834248" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Family Law"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory8">Family Law</label>

  <label for="ci531770282605834244" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Intellectual Property Law"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory8">Intellectual Property Law</label>

  <label for="ci531770283692158976" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Paralegal Services"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory8">Paralegal Services</label>

  <label for="ci531770283696353280" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Legal"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory8">Other - Legal</label>

  </section>

  </div>
  <div class="col col1of3">
  <section class="oOpt jsCategory9">
  <h1 class="oH4">Admin Support</h1>
  <label for="ci531770282584862724" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Data Entry"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory9">Data Entry</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862725" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Personal / Virtual Assistant"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory9">Personal / Virtual Assistant</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862728" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Project Management"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory9">Project Management</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862727" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Transcription"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory9">Transcription</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862726" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Web Research"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory9">Web Research</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862729" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Admin Support"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory9">Other - Admin Support</label>

  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory10">
  <h1 class="oH4">Customer Service</h1>

  <label for="ci531770282584862730" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Customer Service"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory10">Customer Service</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862731" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Technical Support"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory10">Technical Support</label>

  <label for="ci531770282584862732" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Customer Service"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory10">Other - Customer Service</label>

  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory11">
  <h1 class="oH4">Sales &amp; Marketing</h1>
  <label for="ci531770282597445636" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Display Advertising"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Display Advertising</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445632" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Email &amp; Marketing Automation"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Email &amp; Marketing Automation</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445634" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Lead Generation"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Lead Generation</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445633" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Market &amp; Customer Research"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Market &amp; Customer Research</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251343" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Marketing Strategy"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Marketing Strategy</label>

  <label for="ci531770282593251344" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Public Relations"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Public Relations</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445637" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="SEM - Search Engine Marketing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">SEM - Search Engine Marketing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445638" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="SEO - Search Engine Optimization"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">SEO - Search Engine Optimization</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445639" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="SMM - Social Media Marketing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">SMM - Social Media Marketing</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445635" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Telemarketing &amp; Telesales"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Telemarketing &amp; Telesales</label>

  <label for="ci531770282597445641" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Sales &amp; Marketing"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory11">Other - Sales &amp; Marketing</label>

  </section>

  <section class="oOpt jsCategory12">
  <h1 class="oH4">Accounting &amp; Consulting</h1>
  <label for="ci531770282601639943" class="block oOptLbl">

  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Accounting"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory12">Accounting</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639945" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Financial Planning"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory12">Financial Planning</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639946" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Human Resources"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory12">Human Resources</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639944" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Management Consulting"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory12">Management Consulting</label>

  <label for="ci531770282601639947" class="block oOptLbl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Other - Accounting &amp; Consulting"  name="chk[]" class="jsCategory12">Other - Accounting &amp; Consulting</label>

  </section>

  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
  <button type="submit" class="oBtn oBtnPrimary">Save Categories</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a data-action="cancel" class="jsLink">Cancel</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var total = 0;
$('#yyy input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
 if ($(this).prop('checked')) total++;
});
```

Comment: @ David Xu  -  i want to use with ref by id.

Comment: you can't do that, id's are unique for each element on a page, you can't repeat them.